# Is the class of additive groups of rings axiomatizable?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, abelian-groups

I know that it is impossible to axiomatize the multiplicative structures of rings, called $R$-semigroups. Is anything known about the first-order axiomatizability of the class of abelian groups which are additive groups of some ring? I don't want to restrict the meaning "ring" here. I would like to know whether this question is answered for rings with any subset of the set of adjectives {"associative", "unitary", "commutative"} attached.

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that I do want to exlude *some* rings, that is rings with zero multiplication.

Comment: When a subset of your adjectives doesn't contain "unitary," the answer is trivial, because you can take any abelian group and make it a ring by defining all products to be zero.

Comment: ... and every finitely generated abelian group is the additive group of some associative unitary commutative ring, by looking at the classification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finitely_generated_abelian_groups#Classification.
Is there any (necessarily not finitely generated) abelian group which is not the underlying additive group of some commutative ring?

Comment: I realized I forgot to exclude zero multiplication right after I posted but I didn't have time to edit. Sorry! I'm editing now.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Yes, as far as I know there is only zero multiplication on every divisible torsion group.


Comment: @Sean: I assume you mean unitary rings. How about $\mathbb{Z}_2 +  \mathbb{Z}_3+...+\mathbb{Z}_p+...$? Suppose that $\alpha$ is the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\beta$ is the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_3$,... and $k\alpha+m\beta+...$ is the unit in the ring, $k$ is $0$ or $1$, $m$ is $0,1$ or $2$,... . Consider $\alpha*\beta$. Note that $2\alpha*\beta=3\alpha*\beta=0$, hence $\alpha*\beta=\beta*\alpha=0$. Also $(k\alpha+m\beta)*s=s$, $k\alpha*s+m\beta*s=s$ - for every $s$. Taking $s=\alpha$, we get $k\alpha*\alpha+m\beta*\alpha=\alpha$. Hence $k\alpha*\alpha=\alpha$.

Comment: continued: Since $k=0$ or $1$, $k=1$, $\alpha*\alpha=\alpha$. Taking $s=\beta$, we get $m\beta*\beta=\beta$ where $m$ is $0,1$ or $2$. Therefore $m\ne 0$. Similarly all other coefficients of the unit are not zeroes which is a contradiction since the direct sum consists of sums with finite supports. Thus the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2+\mathbb{Z}_3+...$ is not the additive group of any unitary ring. 

Comment: The trivial group, with the only possible ring structure, is unitary, so by excluding zero multiplication you are in some sense excluding too much.

Comment: @Sean: Here is a torsion-free example. Consider a nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb Q$. If it admits a nonzero multiplication, then it is isomorphic (scaling by some rational number) to a unitary subring of $\mathbb Q$. This excludes examples like the group of all rational numbers with square-free denominator.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Why is it important that we include the trivial group? 

Comment: Thanks for the examples. This question is less trivial than I thought. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is No. You can prove this from the work of Wanda Szmielew on the elementary properties of abelian groups. This answer works for any kind of nonzero, bi-additive, binary multiplication (associative or not, commutative or not, unital or not).

In particular, an abelian group $A$ is elementarily equivalent to our favorite  group $\mathbb Z$ iff $A$ is torsion free and of $p$-rank 1 for every prime $p$. The $p$-rank of $A$ is defined to be the minimum of $\textrm{dim}_{\mathbb Z_p}(A/pA)$ or $\omega$. An example of a torsion free abelian group of $p$-rank 1 for every $p$ is the subgroup $S\leq \mathbb Q$ consisting of rationals with square free denominator.

So $\mathbb Z$ and $S$ are elementarily equivalent. $\mathbb Z$ is the additive subgroup of the unital ring $\mathbb Z$, while (as Tom Goodwillie has pointed out) $S$ is not the additive subgroup of any unital ring. In fact, it is impossible to equip $S$ with any nonzero bi-additive multiplication. For, if $s, t\in S$, then $s$ and $t$ are $p$-divisible for almost all primes $p$. By bi-additivity, $s*t$ is $p^2$-divisible for almost all primes $p$. But the only element of $S$ that is $p^2$-divisible for almost all $p$ is 0, so $s*t=0$.